# What options do I have to style select menus in CSS/HTML (no javascript)?

Tags: html, css, select

I want to style a `<select>` menu using only HTML and CSS - what parts can I style and how?

I just tried to upload an image...can't because my reputation is below 10. ANYWHO -

```
<div class="menu-style">
    <select class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; display:block; width:100%; padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px; opacity: 0;color: #fff;border: none; background: #9f4504;">
        <option>Project 2</option>
        <option>Project 3</option>
        <option>Project 4</option>
    </select>
    <div class="selected-item" style="display:block; font-weight: bold;color: #fff;padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px; width:100%;">Selected Project</div>
</div>
<ul class="nav-list" style="width: 100%; display: block; ">
    <li style="display: block;padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;cursor: pointer;color: #fff;">Overview</li>
    <li style="display: block;padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;cursor: pointer;color: #fff;">Reports</li>
    <li style="display: block;padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;cursor: pointer;color: #fff;">Schedule</li>
    <li style="display: block;padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;cursor: pointer;color: #fff;">Forms</li>
</ul>
```

I also have some hover elements going on.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far!

Comment: You can style any part you'd like, however you'd like. That doesn't mean it will look how you want it to though.

Comment: Upload the image somewhere else and just provide a link?

Comment: http://sedesignco.com/select-menu.jpg

Comment: So if you look in the picture, one of the issues I've been having is that my border:none is not working. I wanted no border - I'm now thinking I'll just make it the color of the rest of the buttons.

Comment: And I just tried changing the color code to the background, and it renders the same way. Grrr.

Comment: @user404 You tried changing "outline:none;"? Not sure that'll help for sure

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something yet or done any search?

Seriously... a quick search: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

It's one example, but you got many others on the Web. Start playing around this:

```html
<select>
    <option>Here is the first option</option>
    <option>The second option</option>
</select>
```

```css
select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 34px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that site. I did most of that styling, but I'm still not happy with the select menu I have.

Comment: What do you mean by "not happy with the select menu I have"? What do you have, and what do you want? Maybe use some MS-Paint and upload a screenshot of what you have and edit it to what you would like so I will be able to help you further more.